# How in Scriptui (Extendscript) can I use subscripts or superscripts in button title?

Tags: extendscript, subscript, superscript

How in Scriptui (Extendscript) can I use subscripts or superscripts in button title?  I'm using buttonTitle as an example for any character string that is displayed on the dialog/palette.

In this example:

```js
var win = new Window("dialog");
var buttonTitle = "Button2";
win.aButton = win.add("button", undefined, buttonTitle);
win.show();
```

how do I code buttonTitle so it is "ButtonX" where X is either a superscript or subscript 2?  Or maybe letter Y?  Numbers are available in some fonts but letters probably aren't.  I would like a general solution.

I appreciate your time.
Thanks,
RONC

This is a screen plot of scriptui problem:

[image: See last column 4th row of buttons.]

RONC

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this today, so sorry it took so long.
You can try using unicode codes for this. See the tables on this page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

But those characters sure are tiny! There are codes for letter characters available, but I didn't test any. Here's some code to test, with notes:

```js
function buildUI(this_obj_) { 
    var win = (this_obj_ instanceof Panel) 
    ? this_obj_ 
    : new Window('palette', 'Script Window',[147,196,528,330]); 
    // \u00B2 for super 2, \u00B3 for super 3; the rest are \u2070 for super zero, \u2071 for super one, \u2074 for super four, \u2075 for super five, etc...
    win.xui_ui_button5 = win.add('button', [49,24,177,54], 'Super\u00B2');
    win.xui_ui_button5.onClick = function () {this.parent.close(1);}
    // \u2081 for sub 1, \u2082 for sub 2, \u2083 for sub 3, etc...
    win.xui_ui_button6 = win.add('button', [49,65,177,95], 'Sub\u2082'); 
    win.xui_ui_button6.onClick = function () {this.parent.close(1);} 

    return win 
} 
var w = buildUI(this); 
if (w.toString() == "[object Panel]") { 
    w; 
} else { 
    w.show(); 
}
```

[EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the palette window this code works to create in After Effects]

[image: Screenshot of code working in ae]

[EDIT 2: Here's code that works in Photoshop using a modal dialog (and I'm testing on an old version of PS on this machine, but it should work, but look different on the latest]

```js
var win = new Window('dialog', 'Script Window',[670,456,1160,598]); 
var w = buildUI(); 
if (w != null) { 
    w.show(); 
} 

function buildUI() { 
    if (win != null) { 
        win.xui_ui_button5 = win.add('button', [64,11,231,51], 'Super\u00B2'); 
        win.xui_ui_button5.onClick = function () {this.parent.close(1);} 
        win.xui_ui_button6 = win.add('button', [264,63,431,103], 'Sub\u2082'); 
        win.xui_ui_button6.onClick = function () {this.parent.close(1);} 
    } 
    return win 
}
```

[image]

Here's super x, y and z working in PS, using codes `\u02E3`, `\u02B8` and `\u1DBB`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  With limited fonts in ScriptUI, letter super and sub aren't available with Unicode I believe.

Comment: You must be wrong about that. Have you tried this code? It works.

Comment: I inserted the \u00XX in my code and I get the numbers as subs or superscripts but can't get the letters like "Y".  ABCDEF are available in some fonts but not all I think.   I was not able to get your code to work is reason I used mine but that shouldn't matter.  I'm using VSCode for the ide and Photoshop for program but your code did nothing.  I have it mine set as dialog as I needed to use BridgeTalk to make a palette before and am not going to spend time if it is not directly related to what I need which is XYZ and a few other superscripts.  Thanks,  RONC

Comment: For the record, I'm going to include a screenshot of how the script works in AE. I don't want people to be confused about how this works.

Comment: Thanks for showing your code working.  Palettes don't work that easily in Photoshop.  I don't have AE to try it.  I should have mentioned in my query that I found and tried unicode but couldn't get the letters other than A-F, N, and X.  ScriptUI in Photoshop is really limited versus in AE. I think that only six fonts are usable.  Any way, I just want superscript X,Y, and Z.  RONC

Comment: See the new edit. I don't think you should be thinking about "fonts" with this stuff - you should assume the UI API can handle the full Unicode set. That said, I realize sometimes people want to mess around with how their UI text stuff looks - I just don't like to mess with it, apart from changing colors of the UI text. And yes, you're right about PS not having as many options for the UI. Whenever I create a script in PS or Illustrator, it's always a modal dialog.

Comment: I added the examples for super x y and z, @Ronc

Comment: Thanks.  That works fine for my example but may script displays as x\u0082 not x with superscript y.  Any suggestions. File is ufc-8 with Bom.   RONC

Comment: You need to post the code. The unicode sequence for superscript y is `\u02B8`, which is backslash you zero two bee eight. Not sure how you're getting 0082 ?? (You shouldn't need the BOM, by the way; I'd get rid of it)